# Stacked with "expected a raster or layer name" error

Tags: arcpy, raster

I am using the following python script snippet but I get a TypeError: expected a raster or layer name on the commented line below. I could not find a solution about how to convert the A1 raster (that is correctly created and stored on disk) to be added as addRas.

```
for raster in rasters:
    inputPath = os.path.join(inputFolder, raster)
    print "Processing raster: " + inputPath
    N1 = IsNull( raster )
    A1 = Con( N1, 0, raster )
    if i == 0 :
        # Got an error at the line below
        addRas = arcpy.Raster(A1)
        addNull = arcpy.Raster(N1)
        i = i + 1
        print i
    else :
        addRas = addRas + arcpy.Raster(A1)
        addNull = addNull + arcpy.Raster(N1)
        i = i + 1
        print i
avgRas = addRas / (i - addNull)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

N1 and A1 are already raster objects. Therefore you do not need arcpy.Raster(), which creates a raster object from a **name**.

```
addRas= A1

addRas = addRas+A1
```